# How do I hide a element using jquery on click and when a user clicks away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, show-hide

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show_or_hide_link_clicker').click(function() {
        $(".the_box_to_show").fadeIn(400);
    });
});
</script>
```

When show_or_hide_link_clicker is clicked the_box_to_show is shown.  How do I hide it if show_or_hide_link_clicker is clicked again or when the user clicks away?

Update:  This is what I am doing now:  http://jsfiddle.net/nFbnr/

**Question:** How can i remove the double click requirement ot show the div?

Comment: How can you click again on a link which has disappeared ?

Comment: So you remove in your edit: $(this).hide();  which change in some way your question and so make most answers no more accurate. Well...

Comment: @roasted what i posted was what i thought was right.  I removed it when i saw the comment and realized it was wrong.

Comment: Ha ok, i better understand your statement now! So, thats ok and i understand the toggle comment

Answer (score 2):

When clicking anywhere, check if the element was on the propagation path. If not, the user clicked outside of it so you can hide it.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".the_box_to_show").size() === 0) {
        $(".the_box_to_show").hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vdHAu/

Comment: @starbucks it is not full solution, I am only addressing "clicking away" here.

Comment: new to this stuff not sure how to work arouond it.  thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is what you're looking for.

```
$('.the_box_to_show').toggle();
```

Comment: So how would you use it here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/EKv9H/ - I'd just replace the `fadeIn` call with `toggle`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(".the_box_to_show")) {
        $(".the_box_to_show").hide();
    }
});
$('.show_or_hide_link_clicker').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".the_box_to_show").fadeIn(400);
});
```

Comment: `.is` is a wrong method to use here I think, if you are clicking elements under the box it is considered as clicking the box as well but the `.is` will get a false positive in that case because it only checks if you directly clicked the box.

Comment: I am not sure i am new to this.  let me take another stab at it.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An another way without delegate event to document level:

*you have to set attribute tabindex to the box and CSS outline for style*

http://jsfiddle.net/GV56b/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_or_hide_link_clicker').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(".the_box_to_show").fadeIn(400, function () {
            this.focus()
        });
    });
    $(".the_box_to_show").on('blur',function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.show_or_hide_link_clicker').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
$('.show_or_hide_link_clicker').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).addClass('active);
    $(".the_box_to_show").fadeIn(400);
});

$(document).on('click', 'html', function(){
  $(".the_box_to_show").fadeOut(400);
 });




$(document).on('click', '.active', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```